# Django templates: get the list of passed objects and variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How to get the list of objects and variables passed into a template?

Sultan

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can modify the dict that you passed to render_to_response so that it contains the list of variables.

In your views.py:

```
dic = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dic['keys'] = dic.keys()
return render_to_response('your_template.html', dic)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for variable in keys %}
     {{ variable }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: FYI - this is not giving you a list of variables (the context) passed into the template but rather information about a single dict.

Answer (score 4):

I usually have [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) installed.  It gives you all that information and much more.